# Phonegap, AJAX - PHP Array Issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, cordova

I am in trouble while pass user's input value via array from HTML (Using AJAX) To php page (In fetching Array) .
Is method I use is correct ? I didn't get value in my PHP page.

First I assign user's value to variable

```
var first_name = $("[name='first_name']").val();
var last_name = $("[name='last_name']").val();
```

Then Create Its array.

```
var MyArray = {"firstname": first_name, "lastname": last_name};
```

And Here How I pass value to external server's php file

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: GolbalURL+"updategeneralinformation.php",
        data: "userarray="+ MyArray,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success) {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Ok',
                    // No need for Callback function
                    'Ok',
                    'Ok'
                )
            }
            else {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Something went wrong while attempting update',
                    // No need for Callback function
                    'Atempt Fail',
                    'Try Again'
                )
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            navigator.notification.alert(
                    error,
                    // No need for Callback function
                    'Something wrong',
                    'Try Again'
                )
        }
    });
    return false;
```

Now PHP File code for retrieve Requested array from HTML page and run PHP-MySQL Update Query

```
$get_array = $_REQUEST['userarray'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$db.".users SET first_name='$get_array["firstname"]', last_name='$get_array["lastname"]' ");
mysql_query($query);
   if (!mysql_query($query, $con)) {
  //die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  $response['success'] = false;
} else {
  $response['success'] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
data: MyArray,
```

or

```
data: {firstname: first_name, lastname: last_name},
```

instead of

```
data: "userarray="+ MyArray,
```

at server side

```
$get_array = $_POST;
```

and

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$db.".users SET first_name='" . $get_array["firstname"] . "', last_name='" . $get_array["lastname"] . "'");
```

Note: the mysql_query is deprecated, use pdo or mysqli, and its unsecure in this form (`mysql_real_escape_string()` missing)

Comment: Axel, Thanks for answer but not working, is I need to change anything at "first_name='$get_array["firstname"]" ?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much Axel. its help me alot. And I can also use this method for ADD Statement, right ?

Comment: Yes, I guess, just change needed rows.

Answer (score 1):

You've convert your javascript array into a string when you do this:

```
data: "userarray="+ MyArray,
```

So basically, php just gets a string.
You may want to do this in your javascript:

```
var MyArray = {"firstname": first_name, "lastname": last_name};
data: MyArray,
```

Or

```
data: {"firstname": first_name, "lastname": last_name},
```

And in your php script:

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
```

Comment: Good Explanation user :)

Comment: Glad I can help, Shivam Pandya ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyArray = {"firstname": first_name, "lastname": last_name};
data: MyArray,
```